# Can I parcel a customview(SurfaceView) in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to parcel a customSurfaceView which extends the SurfaceView and implements the parcelable. But I am not able to do. Please someone help  me.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. `Parcelable` objects have to be able to be passed across process boundaries. No `View` can be passed to another process, let alone a `SurfaceView`.